# gnome-panel switches to one row on RHEL6 when opening mail

Tags: rhel

Using RHEL6 I set my gnome-panel to 50 pixels big, it sets the windows in tray to two rows. Great.

**Question:** But: when I open a given mail in my mail client, then the gnome-panel switches to one row, why??

Answer (score 0):

solution: that e-mail had two enters in the subject that made the window name too long.. :D great..